# In zshell how do I make the command line prompt visible

Tags: command-line, colors, zsh

My zshell command line prompt has become almost invisible, I don't know how or why, but now it's white on a very pale grey background. Can someone please give me a command, preferably a short one, that I can copy and paste on to the line so that it becomes visible? My own attempts at typing an escape sequence, to change  the colour, always fail because I cannot properly see what I am typing, nor can I read the error messages that result from that.

I have tried this command:

```
export PS1=$'%{$fg[blue]%}${PWD/#$HOME/~}%{$reset_color%} %{$fg[red]%}→%{$reset_color%}
```

From [this question on this site](https://superuser.com/questions/402281/colors-in-zshell-prompt-cause-odd-behavior), by copy and paste, but it made no difference, as far as I can see, although what arrived on my terminal may not be exactly what is in that reference.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be trivial: this is my experience.

The top line of the terminal window has an `Edit` option, which brings up a short menu, and selecting the `Profile preferences` option opens up another window with several tabs. Use the `Colours` tab to select the theme you want. The setting is preserved through re-starting the computer.

Perhaps I should have looked further into this before posting my question, but I hope this is useful to someone else in the same predicament.