# Strange characters appearing in powershell autocompletes

Tags: windows, powershell, git

Very recently Powershell hasn't been doing auto-completes correctly for filepaths in my cwd. Here is an example of me tabbing after typing: `git add ./.ipynb_` I expect `.\.ipynb_checkpoints\` but instead get this.

```
[93mgit[33m[45m [33madd[33m[45m [33m.\.ipynb_checkpoints\[33m[45m[0m
```

[Screenshot of the powershell window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftTyy.png)

This only happens for git related autocompletes. For instance autocomplete works fine with `py -3`.

I think its related to coloring of the input text going wrong because this is similar to this question: [Strange zsh autocomplete behaviour](https://superuser.com/questions/230301/strange-zsh-autocomplete-behaviour)

But I have no idea how to fix this, any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like [ANSI escape sequences](https://superuser.com/a/1300251/376602)